# Filter Only matching results in ListBox Excel from TextBox text

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user form with a textbox and a listbox. I would like a user to be able to enter text into the textbox, and have the listbox filter results based on their typing.

So far, I have managed to get the ListBox to highlight matching results in the list, but not filter out results that dont match. I have also run into the issue of my code not identifying multiple matching records, not sure what I need to add to get this to happen.

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
        'searches ListBox3 for match and hightlights result. Need to filter results.
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sFind As String

    sFind = Me.TextBox3.Text

    If Len(sFind) = 0 Then
        Me.ListBox3.ListIndex = -1
        Me.ListBox3.TopIndex = 0
    Else
        For i = 0 To Me.ListBox3.ListCount - 1
            If UCase(Left(Me.ListBox3.List(i), Len(sFind))) = UCase(sFind) Then
                Me.ListBox3.TopIndex = i
                Me.ListBox3.ListIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Neither your question nor your code indicates whether you want to allow multiple selections in your listbox or when to clear previous selections. I also wonder why you want to enter the selections in a textbox instead of letting the user select them by clicking in the listbox.

Comment: hence my question, how do I allow for multiple selections in the result? I want the listbox to function as a kind of search tool for the rowsource it is attached to. So as the user types into the textbox, only results that match appear in the list

Comment: In order to permit multiple selections in a ListBox its `MultiSelect` property must be set to `frmMultiSelectMulti` or `frmMultiSelectExtended`. However, I don't understand your workflow. Do you mean to enter words several times in the TextBox adding each to the selection in the ListBox? If so, why not use a ComboBox linked to the same RowSource instead of a TextBox? How do you intend to deselect one item in the ListBox or all?

Comment: I don't want to add anything to the listbox, I just want the listbox to filter what it returns in the user form to match what is typed into the textbox. I did try chainging the frmMultiSelect property but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter listbox values based on a Textbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879261/how-to-filter-listbox-values-based-on-a-textbox-value)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code that works when you exit textbox3, otherwise it will make some filtering while typing and can bring errors.

## If the match is exact

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Not ListBox1.List(i) = TextBox3 Then ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
Next i
End Sub
```

And the loop is made with a recursive loop, otherwise an error appear.

## For partial matches

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If InStr(1, ListBox1.List(i), TextBox3) = 0 Then ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
Next i
End Sub
```

[Found a better code to filter a listbox.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880069/7690982)