# Creation of Userform with several drop-down lists and potential listbox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I'm new to the field of VBA, so I would like to ask your help with Userforms.

I would like to have multiple drop-down lists:

- the **first drop-down** would contain data from `Sheet3`, `Column A`, where I have *project names listed*;
- the **second drop-down** is based on `Row 6` (where *skills are stored*) where I have merged cells in the following way:

  - The columns in `Row 6` are empty until `Column D`, where `Column D` and `Column E` (**subskill1**) are merged. `Column F` is empty and `Columns G` and `H` (**subskill2**) are merged and so on. 

    *In other words, two cells merged, one cell empty, two cells merged, one cell empty, two cells merged, etc.*; and
- the **third drop-down** should be numbers only from **0 to 5**, which represent the values under each person's subskill. 

  Here is a picture of my spreadsheet:
  [image]

Regarding my requirements:

1. It does *not* matter which project the user chooses from the first drop-down list; the second and third drop-down lists will remain the same. **So one list will not affect the other one.**
2. However if the user chooses a project that matches with any of the skills from `Row 6`, then it should show in a Listbox (perhaps, not sure what is the best way) all the people from the given project who got the chosen number for their skills.

I have something like this but not sure how to modify.

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set rData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Me.ComboBox1.List = rData.Offset(1).Value
    Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 6
    Me.ListBox1.List = Me.ComboBox1.List
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, @DKis! Can you please show us a screenshot of your spreadsheet? Right now it's a little difficult to understand how your data is setup.

Comment: So, you want to [`.AddItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/listbox-additem-method-access) to the ListBox `If` specific conditions are matched, to [`Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879261/how-to-filter-listbox-values-based-on-a-textbox-value) the results?

Comment: Here is the printscreen of the excel sheet as you have asked https://s18.postimg.cc/4r0c2pfg9/sheet2.jpg

Comment: So what I would like to do is to have several drop down lists on a user form,, the first one would point at Column A on this sheet and would show the names of the projects, the second one would take the data from Row 5 and show the "mainskills" listed there,  the 3rd one would show the subskills based on the mainskills we took, wo if we take mainskill1 it will only show subskills under it (if it's possible), and as the last dropdown it should ask for a number between 0 and 4, and based on the number it would show a list of the people who got this number under tis project for the given skill

Comment: @TotsieMae please see below

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you have so many cells that are merged? Based on your screenshot, it appears as if the merging is unnecessary (and it can cause issues with formulas). It's generally a better practice to not merge cells as they can cause more trouble than they're worth. There *is* a time and place for merging, I'm just not seeing that this is one of those times.