# Excel Fill Infomation dependent on two dynamic dropdowns

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, dropdown

I'm trying to find a solution for the following problem:

I have a [sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1WoG.png) containing information on several customers with several projects each. The combiniation of customer + projectname is unique.

On a [different sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnNpl.png) I want to be able to:

1. select the customer from a dynamic dropdown-list without duplicates (I have managed that)
2. then be presented with a second dropdown, reduced to only those projects of the selected customer
3. have the information in cells (C5:C7) filled automatically

As the data-sheets content is dynmaic and will contain lots of data, named tables are no option.

I'd be grateful I anyone had an idea on how to solve the problem!

Comment: You tagged your post with [VBA]. So, how about a solution with this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879261/how-to-filter-listbox-values-based-on-a-textbox-value/42880069#42880069?

Comment: This seems very helpful for the first part of my second problem, thank you! It doesn't solve my problem, how to (dynamically) filter those projects related to a specific customer, though.

Comment: sounds like you need dynamic named ranges somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved through VBA. I have written the below code and worked for me.

Input sheet:

[image]

Try the below code.

```
Sub CustomerAndProject()

Dim Customer As String, Project As String, Info1 As String, Info2 As String, Info3 As String

Dim TotalCustomers As Integer, m As Integer

m = 1

'Get Total customers

TotalCustomers = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'First loop to pick customers

For i = 2 To TotalCustomers

Customer = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value

'Second loop to pick the projects related to customer

For k = 2 To TotalCustomers

Project = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & k).Value

'Function r=to validate the duplicate customers and projects

If CustomerValidationForDuplication(Project, Customer, TotalCustomers) = False Then

'Third loop to pick and paste info data related to customer and project

For j = 2 To TotalCustomers

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & j).Value = Customer And Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & j).Value = Project Then

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, m).Value = Customer

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, m).Value = Project

        If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j).Value) Then

            Else: Info1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j).Value

                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, m).Value = Info1

               End If

                If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & j).Value) Then

                    Else: Info2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & j).Value

                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, m).Value = Info2

                      End If

                        If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & j).Value) Then

                            Else: Info3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & j).Value

                            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(5, m).Value = Info3

                             End If

                     End If

                 Next

             m = m + 1

        End If

    Next

Next


End Sub


Function CustomerValidationForDuplication(ProjectToBeVerified As String, CustomerToBeVerified As String, TotalCustomers As Integer) As Boolean

For l = 1 To TotalCustomers

If ProjectToBeVerified = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, l) Then

For m = 1 To TotalCustomers

If CustomerToBeVerified = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, m) Then

CustomerValidationForDuplication = True

Exit For


Else

CustomerValidationForDuplication = False

End If

Next

Else

CustomerValidationForDuplication = False

End If

If CustomerValidationForDuplication = True Then Exit For

Next


End Function
```

Output sheet:

[image]

Let me know if it works for you.

Note: I am new to VBA so my code won't be friendly. Edits are welcome.