# I am getting issue in making Excel data validation list(Drop Down) searchable like excel filter and select/deselect one or more values from the same

Tags: excel, vba, search, excel-formula

I am having a worksheet in excel in which I have created a data validation list in one column. The list have very large number of values so It is very tedious task to scroll through the list. I want to implement the functionality in which a search box will be there to faster retrieval of drop down value. also If there would be some check boxes to select all or deselect all after search results.
I am open for vba approach too please help me with the same .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way I can imagine is a Userform with a TextBox (search) and a ListBox (to select with check boxes). • By the way I don't understand how selecting multiple items for one cell could work at all. I see no sense in that.

Comment: Thanks peh , could you please help me with this approach

Comment: This is a question/answer based website so you need to ask a question to get an answer: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)). Also you will need to start on your own and show the code you already have (because this is no code writing service). We can only assist you to solve your issues on your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter listbox values based on a Textbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879261/how-to-filter-listbox-values-based-on-a-textbox-value)

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about (a purely formula-based solution to) this question since yesterday.

I found a solution that first allows you to create custom filters on lists, and then the data validation drop-down list is chosen from the filtered list.

(If necessary, you can just hide these filtered list helper columns, since there is probably no reason for the user to see them.)

See below, an example dataset that I created, and some example filters.

[image]

The Original List is in column `A`, then the `C` and `E` columns use formulas to filter the list to the left of it, based on the criteria (the yellow cells).

Here is the array formula I have in cell `C2`:

```
= IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,SMALL(IF(LEFT($A$2:$A$8,LEN($B$2))=$B$2,
  ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW($A2)-ROW($A$2)+1)),"(no match)")
```

And here is the array formula I have in cell `E2`:

```
= IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$8,SMALL(IF(LEN($C$2:$C$8)=IF($D$2=0,LEN($C$2:$C$8),$D$2),
  ROW($C$2:$C$8)-ROW($C$2)+1),ROW($C2)-ROW($C$2)+1)),"(no match)")
```

I dragged these cells down to row 8.

Note these are array formulas, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard instead of just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula.

Now the `E` column contains the original list, but with these two filters applied. Of course, you can add as many other extra filters as you desire. One disadvantage is that these formulas are fairly long and need to be created on an as-needed basis, but the formulas do generally follow the same structure if you compare the two formulas above.

Setting up the data validation drop-down list, I used this formula:

```
= OFFSET($E$2,0,0,IFERROR(MATCH("(no match)",$E$2:$E$8,0),ROW($E$8)-ROW($E$2)+2)-1,1)
```

This formula works by returning the list in column `E`, but it only returns the list up to (and not including) the first instance of where `(no match)` occurs.

See below, I have this in cell `G2` in my example spreadsheet.

[image]

Side note: `OFFSET` is volatile and should typically be avoided, but unfortunately `OFFSET` is the only option (that I'm aware of) which allows you to use variable-length drop-down lists in data validation.

With this setup, you can change the fields in cell `B2` and `D2`, which will ultimately filter the data in your original list and this filter will be reflected in your drop-down list.

See a few examples below of this working. Note the drop-down list changes depending on the outcome of the lists based on the filters.

---

***No filters applied***
[image]

---

***Both filters applied***
[image]

---

***First filter only applied***
[image]

---

***Second filter only applied***
[image]