# Run-time error '381': Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listbox, userform

As a single-column listbox, this works and brings back all the data I need, however, upon making this a multi-column listbox, it throws me the error "Run-time error '381': Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index" - see code line `ListBox1.List(1, 0) = MyArray(i, 1)`

Columns are correctly shown when I add the *incorrect* List Property and I've tried adding the List Property where I think it should be, but it shows the whole list again and replaces the 2nd row with one of the correct search results, the 1st row never changes.

Main code is from [How to filter listbox values based on a Textbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879261/how-to-filter-listbox-values-based-on-a-textbox-value) and I've used the comment by @xris23 to amend into the multi-column listbox thus far.

Please help!

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rw As Long
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    Dim sPath As String
        
    sPath = "U:\GroupEmailDataCut.xlsx"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlApp.Visible = True
    End If
    
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath)
    
    Set ws = xlBook.Sheets("GroupEmailDataCut")
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:D" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    MyArray = rng
        
    With UserForm1.ListBox1
        .Clear
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count
                
        If ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 And Trim(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value) <> vbNullString Then
            MyArray = ws.Range("A2:D" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
            For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
                For j = LBound(MyArray, 1) To UBound(MyArray, 1)
                    If InStr(1, MyArray(i, 1), Trim(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value), vbTextCompare) Then
                        UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem
                        ListBox1.List(1, 0) = MyArray(i, 1) '<----Error is across ListBox1.List (MyArray is working as intended)
                        ListBox1.List(1, 1) = MyArray(i, 2)
                        ListBox1.List(1, 2) = MyArray(i, 3)
                        ListBox1.List(1, 3) = MyArray(i, 4)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
        .List = MyArray
    If UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount = 1 Then UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? What line of code gives the error?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev ListBox1.List(1, 0) = MyArray(i, 1) I've put an arrow in the code as to where it is

Comment: `.List` indices are zero-based, i.e. they start with `0` :-;

Comment: @T.M. I can't believe it was that easy...thank you! My next question is it is only bringing up one record when I know there are multiple with the value that I've searched, how do I show these in the listbox as well?

Comment: Add a separate counter ( incremented as last line within the condition check, e.g. `cnt = cnt + 1`), so that you can assign `ListBox1.List(cnt, 0) = MyArray(i, 1)` @WyattR

Comment: @T.M. thank you for bearing with me, as you might have guessed, I'm new to VBA so my knowledge of the terminology and it's structure is very basic. Could you explain like I'm 5? Or point me in the direction of what knowledge I'm looking for, please?

Comment: There are other issues or misunderstandings; I'll have a look the next days and will try to explain the essentials @WyattR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248119/discussion-between-wyattr-and-t-m).

Answer (score 0):

There are several points to observe to make the command button event readable or even runnable:

- Don't address controls by referencing the Userform's default instance *(returning the public members of that object)*,
  reference instead the ***current instance*** starting *either* with the **`Me.`** qualifier *or* simply by naming the userform control alone. Understand the Userform (class) code behind as sort of *pattern* which is blue-printed to the current instance(s).
- You are using `.AddItem` to fill a listbox with items (which is okay for e.g. 4 columns); consider, however that this method automatically builds 10 list columns, but not less or more; this can be avoided .. **a)** by assigning an entire 2-dim **array** to the `.List` (or `.Column`) property or .. **b)** by a **workaround** assigning an *empty* array plus immediate clearing which allows `.AddItem` also for greater column numbers *(integrated in section 2a)*
- **`.List`** indices are **zero-based**, i.e. they start with 0 whereas the **data**field array with its row and column indices is *one-based*: `.List(cnt, c - 1) = data(r, c)` - *See section 2b)*
- Furthermore I separated the check for findings into a help function `IsFound()`, integrated list assignments into loops and tried to make code more readable by some other intermediate variable declarations.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'1) Define data
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'1a)Define search string
    Dim srch As String:   srch = Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value)
'1b)Define data range
    Dim ws As Worksheet:  Set ws = Tabelle1
    Dim lastRow As Long:  lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng     As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A2:D" & lastRow)
'1c)Provide for possible exit
    If rng.Row < 1 Or srch = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
'1d)Get 1-based 2-dim datafield array
    Dim data() As Variant: data = rng.Value
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'2) Fill ListBox
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    With Me.ListBox1
    '2a)Set listbox properties & clear list
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        'Provide for ColumnCount > 10
        Dim ColCnt As Long: ColCnt = rng.Columns.Count
        .ColumnCount = ColCnt
        If ColCnt > 10 Then
            Dim tmp(): ReDim tmp(1 To 1, 1 To ColCnt)
            .List = tmp
        End If
        .Clear                                   ' clear the ListBox
    '2b)Loop through rows & add findings to list
        Dim r As Long, c As Long, cnt As Long
        For r = LBound(data) To UBound(data)     ' 1 ..
            If IsFound(srch, data, r) Then       ' << help function IsFound()
                .AddItem                         ' add item
                For c = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
                    .List(cnt, c - 1) = data(r, c) '<< .List is zero-based!
                Next
                cnt = cnt + 1                    ' increment counter
            End If
        Next
        If .ListCount = 1 Then .Selected(0) = True
    End With
End Sub
```

**Help function `IsFound()`**

```
Function IsFound(srch As String, arr, ByVal r As Long) As Boolean
'Purp.: check if search string is found in given 2-dim array row
    Dim c As Long           ' column index
    For c = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If InStr(1, arr(r, c), srch, vbTextCompare) Then
            IsFound = True  ' positive function result
            Exit For        ' one finding suffices
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**Further links**

- You'll find an outstanding article giving you some insight at [UserForm1.Show?](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)
- Treating the different show modes you might be interested also in [Destroy a modeless Userform instance properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357708/vba-destroy-a-modeless-userform-instance-properly)

Comment: Asking for feedback to your issue dating already of 9/16 as I posted an answer two days later which should solve your issue - feel free to upvote *(up-arrow)* and to accept *(by ticking the green checkmark)* if helpful or to ask if you need further explanations to my answer. @WyattR